Cloud provider external, nodeIp
I'm building a 1.30.3 cluster using external provider and capi.
When the first control plane bootstrapped it does show Ready status but it's internal ip address is .
Because of that cluster is effectively is useless because logs command doesn't work and some other things, plus 2 and 3rd control planes can't be joined.
Error from server: no preferred addresses found; known addresses: []

I found --node-ip param which can be passed to force kubelet to use ip address of the interface, but had no luck with it
I'm on centos9
Here's systemd unit config
Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--node-ip=192.168.5.10"

Kubelet throws this error
Jul 21 03:55:40 controlplane1.local kubelet[48380]: I0721 03:55:40.301183   48380 codec.go:100] "Using lenient decoding as strict decoding failed" err="strict decoding error: unknown field \"node-ip\""

